# How can I take a picture of my database Entity Framework model for people to reference?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My company has made an Entity Framework model of the database with all of the relationships mapped out and I'd like to take a screenshots of that with all of the FKs included in it. But I can't seem to figure out how to take a screenshot that includes all of that information. Any advice?

The "Export as Image" feature of Entity Framework generates an image that is too pixelated.

Comment: Of *my* database?  Good heavens!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the **Microsoft SQL Server Management (Express) Studio** Diagram Option?

(To display the names of your relationships you can use **Database diagram** -> **Show releationship labels**)

[image]

Or you can use Ctrl + the mousewheel to scroll in/out in Visual Studio and you the Snipping Tool to take a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, use [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) to generate diagram from ur Assembly containing EDMX classes

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you have Office OneNote 2007 you can simply print it to "Send To OneNote 2007" printer. Then you can use your favorite image editing tool to cut it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Oh the joy of Visio not being a major player  in this game anymore. you can still reverse engineer a DB using Visio - which gives a nice presentation for printing.

Personally, the VS 2010 Entity viewer (Server explorer) is the easiest and quickest for me to use. The presentation isn't that bad either. Though you have more options with Visio as far as printing and portability. (You can still do Viso -> SQL in Visio 2010 with an addon).

Snipping tool (Vista/Windows 7) Start->Programs->Applications->Snipping  it is such a helpful tool.

And oh am I glad no one actually said: "use your iPhone, take a picture and text it to your boss".