# Where can I find a data designer for .NEt

Tags: c#, .net, database, database-connection

I am looking for a set of components to embed inside my application. The components would allow the user to select a data source, data table/view and edit a query graphically (just like in Visual Studio/ SQL managemenet studio).

Is there such a component in the .net framework? Otherwise, is there a third party?

Comment: are you sure you want to give the user that much power? what if they type in "`DROP Table ReallyImportantTable`" ?

Comment: Good point, Maybe just SELECT would do

Comment: I have always questioned the need for this level of flexibility. Most of the time when I hear a request like this, it means that Development doesn't want to (or can't afford to) take the time to determine what the users actually need, so put all the work on the users' shoulders. Perhaps that's not what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's for reporting and not Little Bobby Tables, you could try a product like EasyQuery:

http://devtools.korzh.com/query-builder-component/

Comment: This is pretty interesting. However, it is pretty primitive. I am looking for something that would have the same look and feel as Visual studio with a diagram. See the following for an example of what I am looking for:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868064/how-can-i-take-a-picture-of-my-database-entity-framework-model-for-people-to-refe

Answer (score 0):

Just load your tables into lists in your code, and bind them to datagrids, then hook their edit events to you can wrap everything up as SQL commands... You basically give user all the control, but restrict him from deleting tables and doing non-standard commands on a friendly UI :)